# Browser compatibility issues other than the obvious layout/CSS issues?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, testing, web-applications, cross-browser

Most cross browser testing tools test for layout differences between browsers. There's not much information on functional differences from browser to browser. I wanted to ask, what are the typical functional problems that can arise in web applications.

Two sources of these problems came to mind right away are Javascript and server-side controls. What else should one watch out for?

Answer (score 1):

There could be differences in the way the HTML is processed, in available Javascript functions, in CSS parsing. For Javascript differences there is a great library called [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) that allows you to easily check if the current browser supports a function.

In general server side controls are just returning html/javascript/css so there's no reason that depending on the client browser they will behave differently, unless there is code specifically to try to account for the browser's differences.

Another great resource for finding out what browser supports what is this [can I use](http://caniuse.com/)